# MouseHandler Events and Delegates c#

Tags: c#, events, delegates, xna, mouse

I have been looking at events and delegates over the last few days and I decided to attempt to make a MouseHandler class using both of these.

Basically I have this problem where the mouse clicks are not registering and the positions for the x and y axis are coming back as 0, by not registering I simply mean displaying in the output console through console.WriteLine(). I have been researching for a while now but I have had no luck so I was wondering if any of you guys could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**MouseHandler.cs**

```
class MouseHandler
    {

        public delegate void MouseEventHandler(object source, MouseEventHandlerArgs 

        public event MouseEventHandler MouseLeftClick;
        public event MouseEventHandler MouseRightClick;
        public event MouseEventHandler MouseMoved;

        public MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

        protected virtual void OnMouseLeftClick(MouseState m)
        {
            mouseState = m;
            if(MouseLeftClick != null)
            {
               MouseLeftClick(this, new MouseEventHandlerArgs() { MouseButtonPress = m });

            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnMouseMoved(MouseState m)
        {
            if (MouseMoved != null)
            {

                MouseMoved(this, new MouseEventHandlerArgs(){MouseButtonPress = m  });
               Console.WriteLine(mouseState.Position.X);
            }
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gt)
        {
            OnMouseLeftClick(mouseState);
            OnMouseMoved(mouseState);
        }
    }
```

**MouseEventHandlerArgs**

```
class MouseEventHandlerArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MouseState MouseButtonPress { get; set; }


}
```

**MouseTest**

```
class MouseTest
    {
        public void OnMouseLeftClick(object source, MouseEventHandlerArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse Left click" + e.MouseButtonPress.LeftButton);
        }        

        public void OnMouseMoved(object source, MouseEventHandlerArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you moved mouse to x " + e.MouseButtonPress.Position.X + " Y pos " + e.MouseButtonPress.Position.Y );
        }
    }
```

**Game1**
Within the update method:

```
mouseHandler.MouseLeftClick += mouseTest.OnMouseLeftClick;
mouseHandler.MouseMoved += mouseTest.OnMouseMoved;
//mouseHandler.Update(gameTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems:

1) It looks like you're triggering the event before checking if the button was clicked or the mouse was moved.

2) You're only getting the mouse state once when the class is instantiated. You'll need to call `Mouse.GetState()` in your `Update()` method.

```
// New class fields
private ButtonState _previousButtonState = ButtonState.Released;
private int _previousMouseX;
private int _previousMouseY;

// New Update() method
public void Update(GameTime gt)
{
    MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

    // Check if the left button was clicked (pressed now, but not last Update())
    if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && _previousButtonState != ButtonState.Pressed)
        OnMouseLeftClick(mouseState);

    _previousButtonState = mouseState.LeftButton;

    // See if the mouse has moved since the last Update()
    if (mouseState.X != _previousMouseX || mouseState.Y != _previousMouseY)
    {
        OnMouseMoved(mouseState);
        _previousMouseX = mouseState.X;
        _previousMouseY = mouseState.Y;
    }   
}
```

Comment: About tracking cursor position, is this code accurate:
`MousePoint = new Point(currentMouseState.X, currentMouseState.Y);` and then simply `string.Format()` the `MousePoint` and draw the `string`? It also has the advantage of `if (Rectangle.Contains(MousePoint)) { ... }`...

Comment: @JohnyP. Sure, you can use a `Point` instead of separate `x` and `y` variables.